# Can´t open DB-connection because it is already opened

Tags: c#, sql-server

My c# code:

```
using (c)
{
    c.Open();
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM [User]  WHERE Username like @username", c))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtuser.Text);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    c.Close();
}
Response.Redirect("Manger Control.aspx", true);
```

Error comes:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The connection was not closed. The
>   connection's current state is open.

Comment: Let me guess - the connection was already open when you called `Open()`. Please post the *full* exception message, including the call stack and mention the *exact* line where an error occurs. I suspect you'd have found the error immediatelly if you debugged the code

Comment: PS: There is no reason to keep a connection open for a long time, in fact it will hurt your application and can cause transactions and locks to escalate if you aren't *very* careful. Create a new connection each time you need one. ADO.NET's connection pooling will make sure you don't really have to create a new connection each time

Comment: Also, just a side not - `Username like @username` should be `Username = @username` since you are not using any wildcards

Comment: @ZoharPeled there is nothing wrong with `LIKE @UserName`, the parameter value can contain wildcards. That's assuming of course that eg deleting all users with a parameter of `%` is acceptable

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos while true, I don't think that's the case here.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I agree, that does look like a Bobby Tables

Answer (score 0):

> > The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open.

The error message itself is very clear. You should check the current state when opening a connection:

```
if(c.State != ConnectionState.Open)
  c.Open();
```

Comment: A better option would be to create the connection when needed

Comment: thanks working but the conection was closed i checked

Comment: @OzCohen how did you check? If this condition worked, it means that the connection was still open

Comment: @OzCohen: He's right. The machine can't lie about that :).

Answer (score 0):

Open your connection at Form_Load() event like below-

```
    SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection();
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (c.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            c.Open();
        }            
    }
```